# How to improve this objects dictionary caching lock in multi-thread (i.e. singleton with parameters)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

```
public class JobModel
{
    static readonly Object _padlock = new object();
    static readonly Dictionary<Tuple<int, string>, JobModel> _jobModelCache = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, string>, JobModel> ();

    public static JobModel Get(int jobId, string model)
    {
        lock (_padlock) {
            JobModel jobModel;
            var key = Tuple.Create (jobId, model);
            var success = _jobModelCache.TryGetValue (key, out jobModel);
            Console.WriteLine (success);
            if (success)
                return jobModel;
            else {
                jobModel = new JobModel (jobId, model);
                _jobModelCache [key] = jobModel;
                return jobModel;
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

The instance constructor of `JobModel` is unfortunately not thread-safe. However, I want to make `JobModel.Get` thread-safe and return the same instance given same parameters.

From [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) I read about that it is better not to do double-check locking.

So my attempt is not very good since it locks on retrieval as well.

Can I get some advice on how to improve the code in my use case?

#### Update

Ok, I think I have found a workaround, from @svick in [is-this-code-thread-safe-singleton-implementation-using-concurrent-dictionary](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27507/is-this-code-thread-safe-singleton-implementation-using-concurrent-dictionary)

> > Never create two connection objects with the same parameters. If one exists, use it.
>
> If you really need to guarantee this, then I think you will need to
>   use locking instead of `ConcurrentDictionary`.
>
> If it's okay to create duplicate `Connection`s (that will never be
>   used) in rare circumstances, then you can use an overload of
>   `GetOrAdd()` that takes a lambda that creates the `Connection`:
>
> ```
> return activeConnections.GetOrAdd(
>     Tuple.Create(param1,param2), _ => new Connection (param1, param2));
> ```

So perhaps I can do

```
public class JobModel
{
    static readonly Object _padlock = new object();
    static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<int, string>, JobModel> _jobModelCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<int, string>, JobModel> ();

    public static JobModel Get(int jobId, string model)
    {
        // Still not perfect, since it might call the instance constructor multiple times.
        // Lock instance constructor as it is not thread-safe.
        return _jobModelCache.GetOrAdd (Tuple.Create (jobId, model), 
                                        _ => {
            lock (_padlock) {
                let ret = new JobModel (jobId, model);
                return ret;
            }
        }
        );
    }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Can't you use a ConcurrentDictionary instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If the code works, this question should be asked on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why do you think normal dictionary is enough? If you need to access it in multiple threads you need a `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: Since you are using lock and the piece of code might be accessed by N no.of threads. So please use ConcurrentDictionary

Comment: Guys, he said "*I think normal dictionary is enough since I am not going to touch the dictionary else where*", so the question should be; why would you use a `lock`?

Comment: @DionV. I understand that as he'll be accessing it from multiple threads, but only from this place no other methods uses it. So OP thinks just normal dictionary is enough(which is false assumption).

Comment: Microsoft isn't going to charge you for using `ConcurrentDictionary`. Please use it. It is free. *Don't reinvent the wheel*.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That would be a matter of interpretation, and as you interpret it, it indeed is better to use `ConcurrentDictionary`, hands down.

Comment: is the data mostly read? How frequent are update?

Comment: Are you afraid that your `Get` method could return two different instances given the same key? Or you're worried about creating the second instance in case of race condition? If former, then it's not true. You misunderstand the docs then.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel my mistake, didn't realize `GetOrAdd` could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't choose `ConcurrentDictionary` since its value might not be consistent.

If you only use `GetOrAdd(TKey, Func<TKey, TValue>)` and don't call any other methods on the `ConcurrentDictionary` (like `AddOrUpdate()`), then the value will be consistent: for a given key, `GetOrAdd()` will always return the same value.

What is not guaranteed is that only one value will ever be created for the key. What can happen is that two threads call `GetOrAdd()` at the same time, which will result in creating two values. But one of them will be thrown away, and `GetOrAdd()` will return the same value on both threads.

If this is not okay for you and the performance of locking always on a normal `Dictionary` is acceptable, then use that.

If it's not acceptable, then you will need some smarter solution. But I don't think normal double-checked locking would work here, because it's not okay to read and write to a `Dictionary` at the same time, while it is okay to read and write a `volatile` reference, if you do it correctly. (Writing a `volatile` reference, as is done in the normal double-checked singleton, is atomic. Writing to a `Dictionary` is not.)